# Firebase asynchronous query - matching results

Tags: android, firebase

Hello fellow developers,

I have a question about getting the data from Firebase.  Trying to compare the transactions list of one user with another user in a function. Two separate hashmaps are used to store the data (transaction list) of each user. Then I loop through the list of records of first user and try to match with the records of the second user. Since Firebase is asynchronous,  function skips before I get the data.  I need some ideas to manage the  asynchronous fetching of data from Firebase.

Thanks

Comment: You should post what you have tried so far... but my suggestion is to nest the database calls. So in your OnDataChange, fetch the second users data.

Comment: Please add the code that you have used so far.